# How can I extract "mlocate.db" contents?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to extract the contents of the `mlocate.db` file to, say, dump it into plain text? Are there any directory or file attributes set for the contents pushed to the database besides the structure mentioned in the man page?

Answer (score 8):

The locate database created by the [`updatedb`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb) command is in essence nothing more than a list of file names. The trivial use case to extract that database is to use a regex or globbing character that matches everything:

```
locate --database /path/to/mlocate.db *
```

or

```
locate -r .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `strings` that comes with the package `binutils` to extract all, or at least most of, the plain text in the file:

```
strings /path/to/mlocate.db >> list_of_folders_and_files.txt
```

The file `list_of_folders_and_files.txt` will now contain what you're looking for.